# importing the react component library with less module in to Nextjs app throws error when building

Tags: next.js, antd, rollup

I have a component library created using react and AntD then bundled it using Rollup, below is my Rollup config.

```
import peerDepsExternal from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve'; 
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs'; 
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescript2'; 
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss'; 
import svg from 'rollup-plugin-svg'; 
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser';

const packageJson = require('./package.json');

export default {   input: 'src/index.ts',   output: [
    {
      file: packageJson.main,
      format: 'cjs',
      sourcemap: true,
    },
    {
      file: packageJson.module,
      format: 'esm',
      sourcemap: true,
    },   ],   plugins: [
    peerDepsExternal(),
    postcss({
      modules: true,
      extensions:['.css', '.sss', '.less'],
      autoModules: true,
      use: {
        sass: null,
        stylus: null,
        less: {
          javascriptEnabled: true,
        },
      },
    }),
    svg(),
    resolve(),
    commonjs(),
    typescript({
      tsconfig: './tsconfig.json',
    }),
    terser(),   ], };
```

I could build this library without any error I did npm pack and installed the package into my NextJS application using "npm install ./<react_component_library-0.0.2-rc.0>.tgz", I can use the component from the library in our NextJS Application if I run in dev mode, but when I attempt to create the build using the "npm run build" but I get below error.

```
monitoring-frontend@0.1.1 build
next build

info  - Loaded env from /Users/nsearch-srinivasan/workspace/frontend/monitoring-frontend/.env.local
info  - Using webpack 5. Reason: Enabled by default https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5
info  - Checking validity of types  
info  - Creating an optimized production build  
info  - Compiled successfully

> Build error occurred
/Users/nsearch-srinivasan/workspace/frontend/monitoring-frontend/node_modules/antd/lib/date-picker/style/index.less:1
@root-entry-name: default;
^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at compileFunction (<anonymous>)
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1065:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/nsearch-srinivasan/workspace/frontend/monitoring-frontend/node_modules/antd/lib/date-picker/style/index.js:3:1) {
  type: 'SyntaxError'
}
info  - Collecting page data .%
```

Comment: Have you tried using plugins like [`next-plugin-antd-less`](https://github.com/SolidZORO/next-plugin-antd-less) or [`next-with-less`](https://github.com/elado/next-with-less)?

Comment: @juliomalves, I am using next-plugin-antd-less, and furthermore, the error comes only if I export the antd's Datepicker component, If I build my library excluding the antd's datepicker component, everything works good with my NextJS application, I can also build the nextjs application successfully.

Comment: @juliomalves, I am following antd document which replaces the momentjs with dayjs  as given here [link](https://ant.design/docs/react/replace-moment). and below is the code recommended in the documentation.   **bold**`import { Dayjs } from 'dayjs';
import dayjsGenerateConfig from 'rc-picker/lib/generate/dayjs';
import generatePicker from 'antd/es/date-picker/generatePicker';
import 'antd/es/date-picker/style/index';

const DatePicker = generatePicker<Dayjs>(dayjsGenerateConfig);

export default DatePicker;`  If I remove the line `import 'antd/es/date-picker/style/index';` I could build.